# C error: Storage size of ‘lcd’ isn’t known

Tags: c

I am getting the following errors while compiling:

```
MenuNavigationApp.c:58: error: array type has incomplete element type
MenuNavigationApp.c:43: error: storage size of ‘lcd' isn't known
MenuNavigationApp.c:338: error: too many arguments to function ‘ucSCPowerUp'
```

Here is my code:

```
int ZealMain()
{
    UCHAR ucStatus;
    struct DisplaySettings lcd ;                       /* line 43 */
    UCHAR seq[]={'0','1','2'},ucKey=0;
    BOOL bStatus;
    UCHAR ucGetStringBuf[3];
    UINT ucGetStringBuf1,uiTimeOut=0;
    UINT ucGetStringBuf2;
    lcd.bFullScreen=1;
    lcd.ucStartPoint=5;
    lcd.ucEndPoint=50;
    lcd.bSelectOption=1;
    lcd.bModeSelect=0;
    lcd.ucSelectedItem=0;

    int uitimeout=30;

    struct FunctionInfo Zealperiph[]={               /* line 58 */

        /* Function information array */

        {"LCD",1,"0",NULL,NULL},
        {"DISPLAY CENTER",2,"00",vLcdDispCenter,NULL},
        {"Display CIRCLE",2,"01",vLcdDispCircle,NULL},
        /* a lot more of these ... */
        {"PRINT DATA",2,"70",vPrintData,NULL}};

    ucStatus=ucMenuNavigation("ZEAL INTERACTIVE",Zealperiph,33,0,uiTimeOut,&lcd);
    if(ucStatus!=1)
        bLCDDispCenter("Values are Incorrect",TIMES8_13);
}

void vPowerUp()
{
    UCHAR ucAtrBuff[50],ucAtrlen,ucStatus;
    ucSCPowerUp(ucAtrBuff, &ucAtrlen,0x27);        /* line 338 */
    vGetCardStatus();
}
```

Comment: You have included the header file that defines the `DisplaySettings` structure?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you have the definition of

`struct DisplaySettings lcd` ? seems missing.

Answer (score 1):

Errors at Line no. 43 and 58 shows that structure definition is beyond the scope where it 
is used . Try checking the place where it has been defined or use extern declaration for this struct ... And error at line 338 shows that ..somewhere u might have given more args bt not changed in the declarations... provided in ur code ..